# Why did Bran Stark start having weird dreams?

Tags: character, game-of-thrones

As we saw, after falling from the tower, Bran Stark started having dreams about the Three-Eyed Raven and a tree.

Did the dreams start after the fall or was he also having the dreams before that incident? Was that incident anyhow related to the dreams?

Answer (score 7):

Prior to the fall, none of Bran's Warging nor Greensight abilities had manifested themselves. The most he had shown was a stronger than usual affinity with his (then unnamed) direwolf, which is an ability he shared with the rest of his siblings. After his fall, those abilities started to show up.

The warging ability was not something unique to him. The rest of his siblings have shown some grasp of it, but none to the extent of Bran's warging prowess. This could be because Bran is naturally stronger, or that his disability gave him more incentive to project it.

The Greensight, however, is something he enjoys alone and only manifests after he falls. During his coma he has visions of the Three Eyed Crow. Spoilers follow:

> It is revealed by the end of Season 4 and the sixth book *A Dance with Dragons* that the visions were sent to Bran by a mysterious person with tremendous powers who calls himself the Three Eyed Crow. His real name is not revealed in the TV series, but it is in the books.

Now, why did the TEC wait until Bran was in a coma to reach out to him? We still don't know. Perhaps during his coma, Bran was more receptive to the TEC's visions, and it is quite possible that it was through these very visions that Bran's latent powers were awakened. In the books the TEC picks Bran's forehead in order to open his third eye, and it is then that Bran awakens from his coma.

Answer (score 4):

He started to have the dreams after the fall, when he was in a coma caused by it.

From [the books wikia](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Bran_Stark):

> While Bran is comatose, an attempt is made on his life by an unnamed
>   catspaw. (...) In the meantime, during the coma, Bran has many
>   visions, including a hazy memory of his falling from the tower and a
>   three-eyed crow that tells him it can teach him to fly.

His abilities of [greensight](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Greensight) and [warging](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Warg) are related to his Stark/[First Men](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/First_Men) bloodline (i.e. he was born with them), but it seems that the fall and the coma following it were indeed the trigger of the abilities.

Answer (score 0):

As per [Game of Thrones TV series Wikia](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Bran_Stark) , he starts seeing the three eyed raven in dreams after fall.

> Bran begins to have a recurring dream in which a three-eyed raven flies into the crypts of Winterfell.

However, if fall triggers this event it is not known. But he started sleeping morea and deeply after fall, that may be one of reason. Or It may be co-incidence that Three eye raven started sending visions at same time.

Wikia also enlisted [Green Sight](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Greensight) and [Warging](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Warg) as his capabilities which results in visions in form of dreams.

> Warging with a Heart tree, a Weirwood with a face carved in it by the Children of the Forest, allows Bran to (combined with his Greensight) have vivid visions of past, present, and future events, including those far away from himself.